# How to get text of below html code

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want the below text.

```
<td colspan="3">
<input type="radio" name="loan_is_a" value="01" class="required" id="loan_is_a">
                First
<input type="radio" name="loan_is_a" value="02" class="required" id="loan_is_a">
                Second            
<input type="radio" name="loan_is_a" value="03" checked="checked" class="required" id="loan_is_a">
                Piggy Back
<input type="radio" name="loan_is_a" value="04" class="required" id="loan_is_a">
                HELOC
</td>
```

I tried .`Text property, innerHTML, GetAttribute` but couldn't succeed.

Can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: There are multiple texts `First`, `Second`, `Piggy Back` and `HELOC`, which text do you want to extract?

Answer (score 0):

I see all are check boxes , you can have all the radio button text in one list and then you can iterate through it.

```
public List<string> getText(){
List<string> list = new List<string>();
IList<IWebElement> radio_option = Driver.FindElements(By.Name("loan_is_a"))
foreach (IWebElement element in radio_option ){  
        list.ADD(element.GetText());
        return list;
    }
    }
```

Comment: This wont help me as I have dynamic xpath before this. //*[@id='loan_information']/table/tbody/tr/td/label[contains(text(),'Loan is a')]/following::td[1]/

Comment: you should have mentioned that in your question. Update the question with exact details.

Comment: IList<IWebElement> list = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(string.Format(loc + "/input[@type='radio']", labels)));
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                    {
                        
                        
                            var radioStatus = list[j].GetAttribute("checked");
                            if (radioStatus == "true")
                                inputDataRow["Value"] = tt.Text;
                        }